# How can I join 2 entity tables if I not have relation between this tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have 2 entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOGS")
public class Logs implements Serializable {
        private Long id;
        private Long userId;
        private String message;
}
```

This entity does not have relations. When `LOGS` fill I do not have `User` entity(but I have `userId`) and I set `userId` in `LOGS` (not `User` entity/ Only `Long userId`).

When I show logs for user on web page I need to show all fields of `LOGS`:

```
id userId message
1  1       message1
2  1       message2
3  2       message3
4  2       message4
```

But I need replase `userId` to `UserName`:

```
id user message
1  Bill       message1
2  Bill       message2
3  John       message3
4  John       message4
```

How can I join 2 tables if I there is no relation between then? I can use native query but maybe it is not necessary?

Comment: Without relation, how will you come to know that message1 & message2 belongs to Bill, whereas message3 & message4 belongs to John?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

In your query you should use the 'old' style on joining when you match the columns in the where clause:

**1)** Create the class for projected fields:

```
package org.myapp;

public class UserLogs{

   private Long id;
   private String username;
   private String message;

   public UserLogs(Long id, String username, String message){
       this.id = id;
       this.username = username;
       this.message = message;
   }

}
```

**2)** Perform the query

```
String query =
   " select new org.myapp.UserLogs"+
   "(l.id, u.username, l.message) "+
   " from Logs l, User u"+
   " where l.userId = u.id";

List<UserLogs> userLogs = session.createQuery(query)
                      .list();

// process list
```

Comment: Yes it is. and my question is how to make the correct mapping to the result that this select will return

Answer (score 0):

You can add a relationship ManyToOne

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOGS")
public class Logs implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Long userId;
    private String message;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;

}
```

Comment: Naturally if I could do so I would have done. And to do so is usually correct. But I said that I can not add a relationship in this situation

Comment: Then first you have a design problem, and second you could use your service where retrieve the Log entity and with the userId, make a search into Users table and populate a new field userName as Transient, but you would do 2 queries by log line.